# MSVC assembly code explanation for lambda call

Tags: c++, assembly, visual-c++, lambda, x86-64

Here is a simple source code,

main.cpp

```
#include <functional>
int main() {
  auto lambda = [] (int a) { return a + 3; };
  int y3 = lambda(5);
  return 0;
}
```

Here is its **cl.exe /FAs main.cpp** output,

```
; Listing generated by Microsoft (R) Optimizing Compiler Version 20.16.27025.1 

    TITLE   main.cpp
    .686P
    .XMM
    include listing.inc
    .model  flat

INCLUDELIB LIBCMT
INCLUDELIB OLDNAMES

PUBLIC  _main
; Function compile flags: /Odtp
; File main.cpp
;   COMDAT ??R<lambda_9xxca4>@@QBEHH@Z
_TEXT   SEGMENT
_this$ = -4                     ; size = 4
_a$ = 8                         ; size = 4
??R<lambda_9xxca4>@@QBEHH@Z PROC ; <lambda_91xxca4>::operator(), COMDAT
; _this$ = ecx

; 5    :   auto lambda = [] (int a) { return a + 3; };

    push    ebp
    mov ebp, esp
    push    ecx
    mov DWORD PTR _this$[ebp], ecx
    mov eax, DWORD PTR _a$[ebp]
    add eax, 3
    mov esp, ebp
    pop ebp
    ret 4
??R<lambda_9xxca4>@@QBEHH@Z ENDP ; <lambda_9xxca4>::operator()
_TEXT   ENDS
; Function compile flags: /Odtp
; File main.cpp
_TEXT   SEGMENT
_y3$ = -8                       ; size = 4
_lambda$ = -2                       ; size = 1
$T1 = -1                        ; size = 1
_main   PROC

; 4    : int main() {

    push    ebp
    mov ebp, esp
    sub esp, 8

; 5    :   auto lambda = [] (int a) { return a + 3; };

    xor eax, eax
    mov BYTE PTR $T1[ebp], al

; 6    : 
; 7    :   int y3 = lambda(5);

    push    5
    lea ecx, DWORD PTR _lambda$[ebp]
    call    ??R<lambda_9xxca4>@@QBEHH@Z ; <lambda_9xxca4>::operator()
    mov DWORD PTR _y3$[ebp], eax

; 8    : 
; 9    :   return 0;

    xor eax, eax

; 10   : }

    mov esp, ebp
    pop ebp
    ret 0
_main   ENDP
_TEXT   ENDS
END
```

Questions for the above example assembly code,

1. What is $T1 ? Original source code does not even have that variable
2. In assembly of source line 7 : There is **lea** instruction which moves address of _lambda to a register. It is not being used anywhere. Why is it so? Is it because compiler missed optimizing it?
3. In assembly of source line 7 : Please explain this statement 
          call    ??R@@QBEHH@Z ; ::operator()

Comment: `$T1` is a temporary the compiler had to invent, and didn't / couldn't keep in registers.  You say optimization is "not disabled", but disabled is the default and you didn't *enable* it with `-O2` or `-Ox`, or even `-O1` which IIRC optimizes for size in MSVC.

Comment: MSVC is using the `thiscall` calling convention for the lambda function. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#thiscall. The ECX register is effectively the `this` pointer and is being passed as a hidden first parameter to the lambda. As peter says, you aren't using optimizations so there is extra unused code being generated.

Comment: @MichaelPetch I didn't disable optimizations. The command I used is 'cl.exe /FAs main.cpp' . Is it that MSVC disabled optimiztions due to the flag /FAs?

Comment: I tried /Od: no change in output assembly. Tried /O2 : assembly instruction reduced considerably. So /FAs is acutally disabling optimization by default.

Comment: okay, tried /Ot too. It is almost similar to original assembly posted in question.

Comment: It has been a long time since I played around with the MSVC options (I got the default wrong), but `/Od` is the default (disable optimization)  according to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/od-disable-debug?view=vs-2019) _This option is the default. Because /Od suppresses code movement, it simplifies the debugging process._ `/FAs` didn't change anything. Since the default is optimization off, just adding `/FAs` didn't change it.